# Set-Cookie Headers ignored by Cache, but can subsequent "Cookie" headers cause session-poisoning

Tags: http, caching, cookies, header

Because of recommendations in documentation, I have added to IgnoreHeaders for Set-Cookie on my Apache disk cache module (hoping to avoid session contamination).  Someone said, won't subsequent Cookie headers get cached and still cause a problem, and I am wondering if that is in fact the case.  I am using Apache 2.2.3 with mod_disk_cache on RHEL Linux 2.6 Kernel

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has the same question:  The logic here is that Set-Cookie is a response Header, and Cookie is a request header.  If no Set-Cookie responses are cached, then only valid cookies should be used by any client (since they wouldn't have gotten a cached one).  Therefore their cookie should be valid and safe.  Seems obvious to me now.